# Disable automatic indentation/spacing of comment symbols in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio

Is there a way to disable TeXstudio's comment symbol formatting? Every time I enter a `%` it automatically adds an extra space even if I backspace and try again (I have to use my mouse and manually click the space to remove the whitespace). It also automatically pulls the `%` forward every time I tab. This behavior is insufferably annoying. I can't figure out how to disable it. Is there a way?

Comment: Very annoying feature indeed; I consider it a stopper when considering to adopt the software.

Comment: Which version do you use? I am on 2.8.6 (Kubuntu 14.04). I can enter a comment without the editor forcing a trailing space after the "%". Note: The editor does however add a leading space if I want close the comment line. So I can write "%This is a comment", save the file and reopen it with no alterations.

Comment: @blue_tiger300: TeXstudio 2.8.4 (hg 4683+:c51d233ca5af+) Using Qt Version 5.3.1, compiled with Qt 5.3.1 R (Windows 7)

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Macros -> Edit Macros` and delete the two entries:

- Key replacement: % before word
- Key replacement: % after word

Comment: This didn't solve the problem, unfortunately. It still adds a space between two `%` if I type them back to back (the intended `%%` automatically becomes `% % `). It also still pulls it forward if I add a tab after typing the `%`.

Comment: After deleteing those two, do you still have any macros defined? If so, do they have a trigger assigned?

Answer (score 0):

To add two comments without space, `%%` instead of `% %` in TeXstudio:

- go to `Macros -> Key replacement: % before word`,

or,

- just simply press `SHIFT + F1` twice.